# Celery with eventlet or gevent doesn't work properly

Tags: celery, eventlet

I'm running Celery using code, like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker = celery.Worker()
    worker.setup_defaults(
        loglevel=logging.INFO,
        pool='eventlet',
        concurrency=500
    )
    worker.start()
```

When running Celery like this, I get the following output :

```
 -------------- celery@some.server.com v5.2.7 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.0-19-cloud-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 2022-12-14 15:23:55
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7fdda296baf0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/6
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/6
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 500 (eventlet)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
                

[tasks]
  . task1

Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b60]
Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b62]
Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b64]
Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b67]
Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b68]
Received task: task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b70]
```

But no task are executed.

If I call `CTRL+C`, a *warm shutdown* is done, and NOW, the tasks are executed

```
> CTRL+C
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b60] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b62] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b64] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b66] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b67] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
[INFO/MainProcess] Task task1[b248771c-6dd5-469d-bc53-eaf63c4f6b68] succeeded in 1.0062870910001s: None
```

One thing odd I noticed here, is that the number of tasks loaded is related to the concurrency parameter. If I set it to 2, I'll have three tasks loaded, and on warm shutdown, 2 will be executed and the last one is put back in the queue.

(uh?)

Now, if I change the *pool* to `gevent`, it loads identically, but NO tasks are executed when I stop the script, instead, they are all added back to the queue.

Finally - AND THIS IS IMPORTANT - If I set the *pool* to `prefork`, it works ... perfectly fine ...

So the issue is not related to my code. Do you have any idea what is going on?

I tried to disable mingle, heartbeat and gossip with no luck.

The versions of `eventlet` and `gevent` are the latest ones of today:

- eventlet : 0.33.2
- gevent : 22.10.2

What is going on? Is Celery compatible with eventlet/gevent or is it just a myth?

Comment: I am seeing this same issue when running celery with `celery_app.worker_main(...)`.

Comment: Yeah,  I went with 'prefork' as the pool ...

Comment: I was trying to benchmark some stuff with gevent and eventlet pools. Opened a discussion on the official celery repo. If this still interests you https://github.com/celery/celery/discussions/8154.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look! If you manage to find why this is happening, feel free to give an answer and I'll accept it if it solves the issue :)